# Missing WKWebView registerURLScheme? in High Sierra

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, macos-high-sierra

So building swift apps on High Sierra - no drag and drop; seems others have lamented the new Accessibility -> Mouse & Trackpad -> Track Options -> Enable dragging; odd not on by default option.

But anyway, the WebView doc page show this method

```
class func registerURLScheme(asLocal scheme: String!)
```

new for High Sierra, but there does not appear to be a similar method for WKWebView - it's lessor successor?   My apps are broken - WKWebView based, and thinking I need to register various scheme, as a WebView does - as local, so that they will be accomodated via app bookmark ala sandbox support.

In related (same?) issue re: Adobe Air and High Sierra - its' broken too, so I feel a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as of High Sierra - 10.13.*, drag-n-drop operations need to be explicitly implemented - re: NSDraggingDestination, you minimally need to implement

```
override func draggingUpdated(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
    Swift.print("draggingUpdated -> .copy")
    return .copy
}
```

and of course

```
override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

These appearing to be optional as drag into my view is affective with just the above triggering a pointer change - my litmus test, but adding these cannot hurt.  Maybe in the future more will also become required.

```
override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
    Swift.print("draggingEntered -> .copy")
    return .copy
}
override func wantsPeriodicDraggingUpdates() -> Bool {
    Swift.print("wantsPeriodicDraggingUpdates -> true")
    return true
}
override func prepareForDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
    Swift.print("prepareForDragOperation -> true")
    return true
}
```

With the emphasis on security, we appear to begin to become more explicit in various kit usages as security tightens.

I'm focused on drags to my apps - NSDraggingDestination, but there might be similar new requirements for drags from apps - NSDraggingSource.